# What happens if kafka stream app don't forward event?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I want to know what happens if kafka stream sink note do not forward current event? Using `AbstractProcessor` Does `process` method get's called with next event from input topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `forward` isn't called, then it acts like a `filter()` in the Streams DSL methods, i.e. the record is dropped from the topology